# Volume of the lattice generated by an ideal

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, integer-lattices

Let $F$ be a totally real number field, $\mathfrak a \subset F$ a fractional ideal. Consider a lattice in $\mathbb R^n$ consisting of vectors $(\sigma_1(v),..\sigma_n(v))$, where $\sigma_1,..\sigma_n$ are different embeddings of $F$ into $\mathbb R$ and $v \in \mathfrak a$. What is the volume of the fundamental domain of this lattice?

If $\mathfrak a = \mathcal O_F$ then the volume equals to $\sqrt{D}$, where $D$ is the discriminant of the field. I suppose that the right answer in general case is $N(\mathfrak a) \sqrt{D}$ but I can't prove it. (The norm is defined as for example in this question: [The norm of an ideal and the norms of its elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266109/the-norm-of-an-ideal-and-the-norms-of-its-elements))

Comment: It has been more than 2 years, but anyway, any news about the question?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the determinant of the corresponding lattice $\Lambda$ is given by $\det{\Lambda} = N(\mathfrak{a}) \sqrt{D_{F}}$ if $\mathfrak{a}$ is a fractional ideal. That is Propostion 2.1 in the paper 'Lattices and Number Fields' by E. Bayer-Fluckiger which was published in 'Algebraic Geometry: Hirzebruch 70'.