# The norm of an ideal and the norms of its elements

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a number field, $\mathfrak a$ a fractional ideal. If $\mathfrak a$ is a prime ideal in $\mathcal O_F$ lying over prime ideal $p\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Z$ then define its norm as $p^f$ where $f=deg[\mathcal O_F/\mathfrak a:\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z]$. The norm continues to all fractional ideals by multiplicativity.

Does the norm of an ideal equal to gcd of the norms of its elements?

Comment: The question has some trouble. In a number field the ring of integers do not always possess the unique factorization property, hence the concept of Dedekind domains. The concept gcd is also not available there. (otherwise it would be a UFD).

Comment: @PVanchinathan: Sorry, but there is no problems in my question. The ring of integers is always a Dedekind domain and in Dedekind domains every ideal uniquely factors into a product of prime ideals. The concept of gcd can be used here as the norm lies in $\mathbb Q$

Comment: @PVanchinathan: Oh, I see my mistake, I meant gcd of the norms of its elements, not gcd of its elements.

Comment: Yes. See section 7, esp. Theorem 7.8, in http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/idealfactor.pdf.